# Taxonomy Dropdown Question

Tags: taxonomy

I need to replace the show_option_all (which show all my taxonomies),

with:

a command to show three taxonomies (ID 14, 15, 16) and label this 'all'

Basically, when someone selects 'all' i only want to show the results of the three taxonomies above.

Note: i cant exclude the taxonomy from the search results as it will effect another search form.

Please help!

My current code is: http://pastebin.com/NJi2LQhY

Thanks

Paul

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide an example of how you're using this. The code snippet you provided doesn't really provide context.

Answer (score 1):

when using `show_option_all` with `wp_dropdown_categories` it gets the value of '0' so you can just check using your `$_GET['property_types']` if it is '0' you know i'll need to show results of "all ID 14, 15, 16"

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for responding.  Would i be able to use this code: http://pastebin.com/iXjGcrc3 ? to filter the show option all? Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

have you read this page from the codex [Filter Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy)